# Saving DAX Meassure to table (ABC /Pareto analysis)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am currently working on an abc/pareto analysis concerning customer IDs.

What I want to calculate is something like this:

```
ID| Sales / ID |Cum. Sales|  %from total | category
G   15.000,00€  15.000,00 €   21,45%      A
D   5.700,00€   20.700,00 €   29,60%      A
H   4.000,00€   24.700,00 €   35,32%      A
Q   3.800,00€   28.500,00 €   40,75%      A
O   3.650,00€   32.150,00 €   45,97%      A
X   3.500,00€   35.650,00 €   50,97%      B
I   3.350,00€   39.000,00 €   55,76%      B
Ü   3.200,00€   42.200,00 €   60,34%      B
Ö   3.050,00€   45.250,00 €   64,70%      B
N   2.900,00€   48.150,00 €   68,84%      B
J   2.750,00€   50.900,00 €   72,78%      C
Ä   2.600,00€   53.500,00 €   76,49%      C
Z   2.450,00€   55.950,00 €   80,00%      C
Y   2.300,00€   58.250,00 €   83,29%      C
L   2.150,00€   60.400,00 €   86,36%      D
P   2.000,00€   62.400,00 €   89,22%      D
W   1.765,00€   64.165,00 €   91,74%      D
R   1.530,00€   65.695,00 €   93,93%      D
F   1.295,00€   66.990,00 €   95,78%      E
V   1.060,00€   68.050,00 €   97,30%      E
B   825,00€     68.875,00 €   98,48%      E
T   590,00€     69.465,00 €   99,32%      E
M   355,00€     69.820,00 €   99,83%      E
C   120,00€     69.940,00 €   100,00%     E
```

This way I can say that "A-customers" make 50% of my total profit.

I used this tutorial to create my meassures:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlUBO5qoKow

```
total_sales = SUM(fact_table[sales])
```

```
cumulative sales =
    VAR MYSALES = [total_sales]
RETURN

SUMX(
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE(ALLSELECTED(fact_table);fact_table[CustomerID];
            "table_sales";[total_sales]);
                [total_sales] >= MYSALES);
                    [table_sales])
```

Since I am calculating the cumulative sales for >1000 unique customer IDs the calculation takes ages!
Is there a way I can save this calculation in a new table so I only have to calculate it once?
Or does anyone know a Meassure that does the same but is less computationally expensive?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate it once as a calculated column but then `ALLSELCTED` wouldn't act as you expect since calculated columns cannot be responsive to report filters or slicers.

There are some inefficiencies in your measure though. It looks like you are calculating `[total_sales]` twice, once inside `SUMMARIZE` and again for the `FILTER`.

I haven't tested this measure, but it may be faster as follows:

```
cumulative sales =
VAR MYSALES = [total_sales]
RETURN
    SUMX (
        FILTER (
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
                fact_table[CustomerID];
                ALLSELECTED ( fact_table );
                "table_sales"; [total_sales]
            );
            [table_sales] >= MYSALES
        );
        [table_sales]
    )
```

The important part is reusing `[table_sales]` in the `FILTER` but [SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-summarizecolumns/) might be a bit better too.

Comment: Cheers! reusing [table_sales] helped a lot but it's still runnig super slow.
I have tried the calculated column option which worked almost.
(New table -> `table = SUMMARIZE(fact_table; fact_table[IDs];"Cum Sales"; [cumulative sales]` ).

For some reason the ID with highest sales has a blank cumulative value (Given the example above it looks like this :

ID: "D" would have 5.700€ sales; 15.000€ Cum. Sales;

ID: "H" would have 4.000€ sales and 20.700€ Cum. Sales.

So the Cumulative Sales is moved one row down. Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: No idea unless you accidentally wrote `>` instead of `>=`.